# React Refine framework and mui autocomplete dropdown menus with prefilled values from fetched data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, react-hook-form, refinejs

I am working on a project with the refine framework for user registry management. In this application, it is possible to create dedicated processes for each user, and for each process, I can associate dashboards and specific users. On the Edit page for processes, I've built two dropdown menus with an autocomplete function that are populated by data from two API calls, `fetchUsers()` and `fetchDashboards()`. Up to this point, everything works perfectly. Now, since each process potentially already contains users or associated dashboards, I would like the dropdown menus to have these values pre-filled in the respective menus. This last part doesn't seem to work because when I refresh the page, the menus are empty, despite the arrays being correctly populated. How can I get the data for users already associated with the process `processDetails?.dashboards.map((dashboard) => dashboard.title)` and for the dashboards associated with the process `processDetails?.users.map((user) => user.email)` and pre-fill them in the corresponding menus?

This is my component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import { useForm } from "@refinedev/react-hook-form";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

import { Create } from "@refinedev/mui";
import { Box, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";

const API_URL = "http://localhost:3500/api/v1";

export const ProcessEdit = () => {
  const {
    control,
    saveButtonProps,
    refineCore: { formLoading },
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const { id } = useParams();

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [dashboards, setDashboards] = useState([]);
  const [processDetails, setProcessDetails] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/users`);
        const usersData = response.data.data.map((user) => ({
          label: user.email,
        }));
        setUsers(usersData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Fetching error", error);
      }
    };

    fetchUsers();

    const fetchDashboards = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/dashboards`);
        const dashboardsData = response.data.data.map((dashboard) => ({
          label: dashboard.title,
        }));
        setDashboards(dashboardsData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Fetching error", error);
      }
    };

    fetchDashboards();

    const fetchProcessDetails = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/processes/${id}`);
        setProcessDetails(response.data.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(
          "Fetching error",
          error
        );
      }
    };

    fetchProcessDetails();
  }, []);

  console.log(
    processDetails?.users.map((user) => ({
      label: user.email,
    }))
  );
  console.log(
    processDetails?.dashboards.map((dashboard) => ({
      label: dashboard.title,
    }))
  );
  console.log(users);
  console.log(dashboards);

  return (
    <Create
      isLoading={formLoading}
      saveButtonProps={saveButtonProps}
      title={<Typography variant="h5">Modify Process</Typography>}
    >
      <Box
        component="form"
        sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}
        autoComplete="off"
      >
        <Controller
          name="name"
          control={control}
          defaultValue=""
          rules={{ required: "This field must not be empty" }}
          render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
            <TextField
              {...field}
              label="Process name"
              margin="normal"
              fullWidth
              error={!!error}
              helperText={error ? error.message : null}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Controller
          name="description"
          control={control}
          defaultValue=""
          render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
            <TextField
              {...field}
              label="Process description"
              margin="normal"
              fullWidth
              error={!!error}
              helperText={error ? error.message : null}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Controller
          name="users"
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Autocomplete
              {...field}
              multiple
              id="users-autocomplete"
              options={users}
              defaultValue={
                processDetails
                  ? processDetails?.users.map((user) => ({
                      label: user.email,
                    }))
                  : []
              }
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
              value={users.filter((email) =>   field.value.includes(email.label))}
              onChange={(_, data) => {
                const newValue = data.map((d) => d.label);
                field.onChange(newValue);
              }}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  label="Users"
                  margin="normal"
                  error={!!errors.users}
                  helperText={errors.users?.message}
                />
              )}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Controller
          name="dashboards"
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Autocomplete
              {...field}
              multiple
              id="dashboards-autocomplete"
              options={dashboards}
              defaultValue={
                processDetails
                  ? processDetails?.dashboards.map((dashboard) => ({
                      label: dashboard.title,
                    }))
                  : []
              }
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
              value={dashboards.filter((dashboard) =>
                field.value.includes(dashboard.label)
              )}
              onChange={(_, data) => {
                const newValue = data.map((d) => d.label);
                field.onChange(newValue);
              }}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  label="Dashboards"
                  margin="normal"
                  error={!!errors.dashboards}
                  helperText={errors.dashboards?.message}
                />
              )}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Box>
    </Create>
  );
};
```

If I click on the menus, I actually see the list of user's `emails [{label: "email@email.com"},{},...]` and the titles of the dashboards `[{label: "Sales"},{},...]`, but I do not see the pre-filled values that are already associated with the process. From `console.log`, the arrays of values that should be pre-filled also have the same structure: `[{label: "currentEmail@email.com"},{},...]` and `[{label: "currentDashboard"},{},...]`.